# Failed launching test session: Error: Couldn't initialise "@wdio/cucumber-framework". Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]

Tags: typescript, cucumber, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I installed @wdio/cli through '*npm i --save-dev @wdio\cli*'.
Then, I did '*npx wdio init*' selected 'cucumber', 'selenium-standalone-service', 'typescript', 'allure' and default options in remainings.

It downloaded sample feature files along with step-definitions and page-object .ts file. I made no change in any file apart from adding the tsconfig.json file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES2020",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "lib": ["DOM", "ES2020"],
  "strict": false,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "types": [
     "node",
     "expect-webdriverio",
     "webdriverio/async",
     "@wdio/cucumber-framework",
     "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service"
   ]
 },
  "include": ["./features/**/*.ts", "*conf*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules"]
}
```

On executing 'npx wdio wdio.config.ts', I got the below error.
Find the code here: https://github.com/krsnasngh/wdio-cucumber-ts

```
ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: Error: Couldn't initialise "@wdio/cucumber-framework".
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/formatter/helpers/event_data_collector' is not defined by "exports" in F:\ABD\Codes\VSCodes\Automations\WebDriverIOs\wdio-cucumber\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\package.json
    at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:290:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:513:3)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:432:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:472:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:867:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\ABD\Codes\VSCodes\Automations\WebDriverIOs\wdio-cucumber\node_modules\@wdio\cucumber-framework\build\index.js:33:48)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\Users\Krishna Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1045:43)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.safeRequire (F:\ABD\Codes\VSCodes\Automations\WebDriverIOs\wdio-cucumber\node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\utils.js:183:15)
    at Object.initialisePlugin (F:\ABD\Codes\VSCodes\Automations\WebDriverIOs\wdio-cucumber\node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\initialisePlugin.js:30:34)
    at Runner.run (F:\ABD\Codes\VSCodes\Automations\WebDriverIOs\wdio-cucumber\node_modules\@wdio\runner\build\index.js:81:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Due To v7.2.0 @cucumber/cucumber release, This error is being observed. The same code is expected to work fine on @cucumber/cucumber v7.1.0.
Please Refer: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/1646